# Fixing a proof of the multivariable chain rule

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem** Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $G: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$. If $F$ is differentiable at $P$ and $G$ is differentiable at $F(P)$ then $G\circ F$ is differentiable at $P$.

**Proof from my calculus book**
For proving the limit of the diffentiability at $P$ we need to bound:
$\frac{|| G\circ F(x)-G\circ F(P)- DG_{F(P)}DF_P(X-P)||}{||X-P||} = \frac{|| G\circ F(x)-G\circ F(P)- DG_{F(P)}DF_P(X-P) - DG_{F(P)}(F(x)-F(P)) +  DG_{F(P)}(F(x)-F(P))||}{||X-P||} \leq 
\frac{|| G\circ F(x)-G\circ F(P)-DG_{F(P)}(F(X)-F(P)||)}{||X-P||} + \frac{||DG_{F(P)}||_{\infty}||F(X)-F(P)-DF_P(X-P)||}{||X-P||}$

Because of differentiability the of $F$ the second term tends to $0$.

The first one $\frac{|| G\circ F(x)-G\circ F(P)-DG_{F(P)}(F(X)-F(P)||)}{||X-P||} = \frac{|| G\circ F(x)-G\circ F(P)-DG_{F(P)}(F(X)-F(P)||)||F(X)-F(P)||}{||F(X)-F(P)|| ||X-P||}$
and because of continuity of $F$ at $P$ and differentiability of $G$ at $F(P)$ this tends to $0$. $\blacksquare$

But this only works when $F(x) \neq F(P)$, and the book doesn't mention how to solve the other case.  Is it correct to say that if $F(x)=F(P)$ then evaluating the function we need to bound it's $0$ so we can only focus on $F(x)\neq F(P)$?

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to observe that if $F(x)=F(P)$ F is constant?

Comment: $x$ is a vector value, so a function that is constant only in a segment that passes through $P$ has the same problem and $F$ doesn't have to be constant in all the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Frechet derivatives.  The same result is true for the weaker Hadamard derivative, but the argument slightly more complicated.
I simplify the notation a bit: I hope you don't mind.

It is easier to see with the a fractionless formulation: $f$ differentiable at $p$ means $$f(p+h)=f(p)+\langle df(p),h\rangle + \|h\|\epsilon_1(h)$$ and $g$ differentiable at $q$ means $$g(q+k)=g(q)+\langle dg(q),k\rangle + \|k\|\epsilon_2(k),$$ where the $\lim_{h\to0}\epsilon_1(h)=0$ and  $\lim_{k\to0}\epsilon_2(k)=0.$  Apply this to $q=f(p)$ and $k=\langle df(p),h\rangle + \|h\|\epsilon_1(h),$ and gather terms.  Note that  $h\to 0$ implies $k\to 0$ and indeed $\|k\| = O(\|h\|)$ which allows you to show that the error term $E$ in $$g(f(p+h)) = g(f(p)) + \langle dg(f(p))df(p),h\rangle + E $$
is of the form $E=\|h\|\epsilon_3(h)$ for some $\epsilon_3$ for which $\epsilon_3(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.

This all hinges on seeing that the usual definition of derivative and differentiability at $x$ is equivalent to asserting that the error $E$ in the first order "Taylor approximation" $f(x+h) = f(x)+\langle df(x),h\rangle+E$ is of order $E=o(\|h\|)$.